# App going to home screen after some time without error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

App in Unity works perfectly, but when on Android device, after about 3 minutes it automatically going to the home screen, without any error pop up, etc. just close the app.

I run logcat and I must say I'm a bit lost in that file. But I found this error (will this be responsible for my issue? how to fix it? )

whole logcat file if this help.

[LOGCAT FILE](https://easyupload.io/t337u0)

package name: com.fGamesCreation.FitIt

```
08-25 22:44:17.309 11464 11464 W System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.samsung.android.scloud.app.ui.settings.controller.notification.SyncAndBackupSettingNotificationManager
08-25 22:44:17.316 11464 11521 I [SC][AUTH]: [RequestAuthStrategy]execute. OUT
08-25 22:44:17.316 11464 11464 W System.err:    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
08-25 22:44:17.316 11464 11464 W System.err:    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
08-25 22:44:17.316 11464 11464 W System.err:    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379)
08-25 22:44:17.316 11464 11464 W System.err:    at com.samsung.android.scloud.app.core.operators.notification.NotificationRBManager.addNotificationManager(NotificationRBManager.java:80)
08-25 22:44:17.317 11464 11464 W System.err:    at com.samsung.android.scloud.app.core.operators.notification.NotificationManagerFactory.addNotificationManager(NotificationManagerFactory.java:48)
08-25 22:44:17.317 11464 11464 W System.err:    at com.samsung.android.scloud.app.core.operators.notification.NotificationOperator.onStarted(NotificationOperator.java:78)
08-25 22:44:17.317 11464 11464 W System.err:    at com.samsung.android.scloud.app.framework.Operators.notifyOperatorsStarted(Operators.java:374)
08-25 22:44:17.317 11464 11464 W System.err:    at com.samsung.android.scloud.app.framework.Operators.initialize(Operators.java:333)
08-25 22:44:17.317 11464 11464 W System.err:    at com.samsung.android.scloud.app.framework.Operators.<init>(Operators.java:132)
08-25 22:44:17.317 11464 11464 W System.err:    at com.samsung.android.scloud.app.framework.Operators.<clinit>(Operators.java:55)
08-25 22:44:17.317 11464 11464 W System.err:    at com.samsung.android.scloud.app.core.manager.OperatorManagerInvocationHandler$OperatorManagerImpl.<init>(OperatorManagerInvocationHandler.java:63)
08-25 22:44:17.317 11464 11464 W System.err:    at com.samsung.android.scloud.app.core.manager.OperatorManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(OperatorManagerInvocationHandler.java:51)
08-25 22:44:17.317 11464 11464 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
08-25 22:44:17.317 11464 11464 W System.err:    at $Proxy0.offerOperation(Unknown Source)
08-25 22:44:17.317 11464 11464 W System.err:    at com.samsung.android.scloud.app.OperatorInitializer.initialize(OperatorInitializer.java:15)
08-25 22:44:17.317 11464 11464 W System.err:    at com.samsung.android.scloud.app.SamsungCloudApp.lambda$onCreate$0$SamsungCloudApp(SamsungCloudApp.java:59)
08-25 22:44:17.317 11464 11464 W System.err:    at com.samsung.android.scloud.app.-$$Lambda$SamsungCloudApp$16k4Kd-qNmt5F5o0hoM4zP1iKO8.accept(Unknown Source:4)
08-25 22:44:17.317 11464 11464 W System.err:    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
08-25 22:44:17.317 11464 11464 W System.err:    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:604)
08-25 22:44:17.317 11464 11464 W System.err:    at com.samsung.android.scloud.app.SamsungCloudApp.onCreate(SamsungCloudApp.java:59)
08-25 22:44:17.317 11464 11464 W System.err:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1190)
08-25 22:44:17.317 11464 11464 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6859)
08-25 22:44:17.317 11464 11464 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:268)
08-25 22:44:17.317 11464 11464 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1982)
08-25 22:44:17.318 11464 11464 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
08-25 22:44:17.318 11464 11464 W System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
08-25 22:44:17.318 11464 11464 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
08-25 22:44:17.318 11464 11464 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-25 22:44:17.318 11464 11464 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
08-25 22:44:17.318 11464 11464 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
08-25 22:44:17.318 11464 11464 W System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.samsung.android.scloud.app.ui.settings.controller.notification.SyncAndBackupSettingNotificationManager
08-25 22:44:17.318 11464 11464 W System.err:    ... 30 more
08-25 22:44:17.320  1276 10975 I ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageWhitelisted:com.osp.app.signin user:0
08-25 22:44:17.320  1276 10975 D ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageWhitelisted: DO is not enabled on user 0. Allowed.
08-25 22:44:17.320  1276 10975 D ActivityManager: package  com.osp.app.signin, user - 0 is SDcard whitelisted
08-25 22:44:17.320  1276 10975 I ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted:com.osp.app.signin user:0
08-25 22:44:17.320  1276 10975 D ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted: DO is not enabled on user 0. Allowed.
08-25 22:44:17.320  1276 10975 I ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted:com.osp.app.signin user:0
08-25 22:44:17.320  1276 10975 D ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted: DO is not enabled on user 0. Allowed.
08-25 22:44:17.321  1276 10975 W ActivityManager: wait for provider publish: waiters=1 callerApp=ProcessRecord{77beea7 11464:com.samsung.android.scloud/5009} cpr=ContentProviderRecord{ea5af54 u0 com.osp.app.signin/com.samsung.android.samsungaccount.authentication.data.OpenContentProvider}
08-25 22:44:17.338  1276 11523 D WifiConnectivityMonitor.DnsPingerHandler: set
```

Comment: The error in the log happens in `com.samsung.android.scloud.app.ui.settings.controller.notification.SyncAndBackupSettingNotificationManager`. I suppose you are not working on Samsung firmware and it's unrelated to your app.

Comment: "I'm bit lost in that file" - well, you are not the only one who is.

Comment: You should check the logs for a stacktrace that includes the package name of your app.

Comment: I add whole logcat file to download. Maybe there is more to it than what I posted

Comment: You can try using Cloud Diagnostics from unity, you can see all crashes if you go to unity dashboard/your project/cloud diagnostics/crashes and exceptions. (1. You need to enable cloud diagnostics in unity services within the app/game you are developing in the editor. 2. I'm not sure if this is free or not, just check it) Hope it helps. If you have any further questions about the tool just tag me

Comment: @sswwqqaa  I installed etc. I see some exceptions but from earlier in the morning when I was working on the app. But nothing that have to do with my current problem, the app still turning off after 3 minutes and no crash or exception is detected in Could Diagnostics.  Really don't know what to do hehe

Comment: I would check logcat one more time, looking for your package name and the exact time when the app crashed. Then you can paste smaller log from the crash and maybe someone can help you with that. Important thing is to make sure that it actually crashes. Can you unminimize it? or you need to launch it again?